# MySql trigger not executed when new rows come in over JDBC connection?

Tags: java, mysql, triggers, spring-data

I'm trying to track revisions to data over time.
I've decided to use the 'id, revision' pattern.
Note that neither key field is an AUTO_INCREMENT - I'm using a BEFORE INSERT trigger to calculate
what id and revision the new row should get. Yes I could handle all this on the application side
but choose to do it on the db side.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE person (
  id BIGINT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  revision BIGINT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id, revision)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person_debug;
CREATE TABLE person_debug (
  id BIGINT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  revision BIGINT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  message varchar(40),
  PRIMARY KEY ( id, revision)
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER person_insert BEFORE INSERT ON person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE new_id BIGINT;
DECLARE new_revision BIGINT;
DECLARE row_cnt BIGINT;
IF( NEW.id IS NULL) THEN
  SET new_id = 1;
  SET new_revision = 0;
  SET row_cnt = (SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'person' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE');
  IF( row_cnt > 0 ) THEN
    SET new_id = (SELECT MAX( id) + 1 FROM person);
  END IF;
ELSE
  SET new_id = NEW.id;
  SET new_revision = (SELECT MAX( revision) + 1 FROM person WHERE id = new_id);
  INSERT INTO person_debug VALUES ( new_id, new_revision, "tried an update");
END IF;
SET NEW.id = new_id;
SET NEW.revision = new_revision;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO person ( id, last_name, first_name) VALUES
  ( null, 'Hamilton', 'Mike'),
  ( null, 'Jefferson', 'Thomas'),
  ( null, 'Nixon', 'Richard'),
  ( null, 'Ford', 'Gerald'),
  ( null, 'Reagan', 'Ronald'),
  ( null, 'Lincoln', 'Abraham')
  ( null, 'Roosevelt', 'Teddy')
  ( null, 'Hayden', 'Rutherford')
;

INSERT INTO person ( id, last_name, first_name) VALUES
  (    1, 'Hamilton', 'Alexis'),
  (    8, 'Hays', 'Rutherford')
  (    1, 'Hamilton', 'Alexander')
;
```

this all works perfectly when I run the run the script manually from within an MySql session

```
source create_tables.sql

select * from person;

  id| revision| last_name  | first_name
====================================
   1|        0| 'Hamilton' | 'Mike'
   1|        1| 'Hamilton' | 'Alexis'
   1|        2| 'Hamilton' | 'Alexander'
   2|        0| 'Jefferson'| 'Thomas'
   3|        0| 'Nixon'    | 'Richard'
   4|        0| 'Ford'     | 'Gerald'
   5|        0| 'Reagan'   | 'Sylvester'
   6|        0| 'Lincoln'  | 'Abraham'
   7|        0| 'Roosevelt'| 'Teddy'
   8|        0| 'Hayden'   | 'Rutherford'
   8|        1| 'Hays'     | 'Rutherford'

select * from person_debug;

  id| revision| message
====================================
   1|        1| 'tried an update'
   1|        2| 'tried an update'
   8|        1| 'tried an update'
```

Fantastic. All parts of the trigger are being executed and they all work exactly as expected.

Now I have a Java/SpringData/MVC/MySql webapp built up in which a page contains a table containing
the contents of person as rows and you can select a row, choose to update the row, which populates a popup form
which you edit then submit, which then goes back to a controller which instantiates a new Person entity and sends
it along to the database.

The problem is when I then try to update a person the ORIGINAL row gets UPDATED and no new row gets inserted.
Example, submitting the update form with
       5|        0| 'Reagan'   | 'Ronald'

should result in

```
select * from person;

  id| revision| last_name  | first_name
====================================
   1|        0| 'Hamilton' | 'Mike'
   1|        1| 'Hamilton' | 'Alexis'
   1|        2| 'Hamilton' | 'Alexander'
   2|        0| 'Jefferson'| 'Thomas'
   3|        0| 'Nixon'    | 'Richard'
   4|        0| 'Ford'     | 'Gerald'
   5|        0| 'Reagan'   | 'Sylvester'
   5|        1| 'Reagan'   | 'Ronald'
   6|        0| 'Lincoln'  | 'Abraham'
   7|        0| 'Roosevelt'| 'Teddy'
   8|        0| 'Hayden'   | 'Rutherford'
   8|        1| 'Hays'     | 'Rutherford'

select * from person_debug;

  id| revision| message
====================================
   1|        1| 'tried an update'
   1|        2| 'tried an update'
   5|        1| 'tried an update'
   8|        1| 'tried an update'
```

but instead I get

```
select * from person;

  id| revision| last_name  | first_name
====================================
   1|        0| 'Hamilton' | 'Mike'
   1|        1| 'Hamilton' | 'Alexis'
   1|        2| 'Hamilton' | 'Alexander'
   2|        0| 'Jefferson'| 'Thomas'
   3|        0| 'Nixon'    | 'Richard'
   4|        0| 'Ford'     | 'Gerald'
   5|        0| 'Reagan'   | 'Ronald'
   6|        0| 'Lincoln'  | 'Abraham'
   7|        0| 'Roosevelt'| 'Teddy'
   8|        0| 'Hayden'   | 'Rutherford'
   8|        1| 'Hays'     | 'Rutherford'

select * from person_debug;

  id| revision| message
====================================
   1|        1| 'tried an update'
   1|        2| 'tried an update'
   8|        1| 'tried an update'
```

it's as if the trigger isn't executed when a row is to be added
when the row comes in over the JDBC connection from the webapp.

Any ideas?

TIA,

code_warrior

Comment: "The problem is when I then try to **update** a person the ORIGINAL row gets **UPDATED** and no new row gets inserted." i only see the trigger  "CREATE TRIGGER person_insert BEFORE **INSERT** ON person"  You need to write a other trigger that handles the `UPDATE` case.. Copy paste the code and change "CREATE TRIGGER person_insert BEFORE **INSERT** ON person into "CREATE TRIGGER person_insert BEFORE **UPDATE** ON person" then it should work.

Comment: Note that calculating the primary key as `MAX(id)+1` is not reliable if you have more than one client inserting concurrently. It creates a race condition. This is why auto-increment id's exist, so they can allocate id's in a manner that is thread-safe and outside the scope of any transaction.

Comment: To Raymond: No row should ever get updated in the table, only new rows inserted. An update in this context means a new row gets inserted with the same id an incremented revision number.

Comment: To Bill: yes this is the correct and scalable approach and I will likely backtrack to it - this whole exercise grew out of a desire to figure out how to make composite keys work for entities inside a webapp.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the part " which then goes back to a controller which instantiates a new Person entity and sends it along to the database". It clearly does not do that. For MySQL, an `insert` (without fancy stuff like `on duplicate key` or something) stays an `insert` and can only add new rows, not update (or delete) existing ones, it's technically not (yet) possible. You clearly updated a row. You can verify that by adding an `on update`-trigger that just logs something. So check your controller or add it to your (probably new) question, it's not a problem of your trigger.